# Alternative to AWS's Security groups in GCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, aws-security-group

Is there an alternative to AWS's security groups in the Google Cloud Platform?

Following is the situation which I have:

1. A Basic Node.js server running in Cloud Run as a docker image.
2. A Postgres SQL database at GCP.
3. A Redis instance at GCP.

What I want to do is make a 'security group' sort of so that my Postgres SQL DB and Redis instance can only be accessed from my Node.js server and nowhere else. I don't want them to be publically accessible via an IP.

What we do in AWS is, that only services part of a security group can access each other.

I'm not very sure but I guess in GCP I need to make use of Firewall rules (not sure at all).

If I'm correct could someone please guide me as to how to go about this? And if I'm wrong could someone suggest the correct method?

Comment: If one is familiar with AWS then [Google Cloud for AWS Professionals](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws) helps to get comfortable with GCP. Usually most of the clouds have common features like virtual servers, object storage etc and then they differentiate one from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @amsh for the solution to the problem. But there were a few more things that were required to be done so I guess it'll be better if I list them out here if anyone needs in the future:

- Create a `VPC network` and add a subnet for a particular region (Eg: us-central1).
- Create a VPC connector from the `Serverless VPC Access` section for the created VPC network in the same region.
- In `Cloud Run` add the created VPC connector in the `Connection` section.
- Create the PostgreSQL and Redis instance in the **same** region as that of the created VPC network.
- In the `Private IP` section of these instances, select the created VPC network. This will create a Private IP for the respective instances in the region of the created VPC network.
- Use this Private IP in the Node.js server to connect to the instance and it'll be good to go.

**Common Problems you might face:**

- **Error while creating the VPC Connector:** Ensure the IP range of the VPC connector and the VPC network do not overlap.
- **Different regions:** Ensure all instances are in the same region of the VPC network, else they won't connect via the Private IP.
- **Avoid changing the firewall rules:** The firewall rules must not be changed unless you need them to perform differently than they normally do.
- **Instances in different regions:** If the instances are spread across different regions, use `VPC network peering` to establish a connection between them.

Answer (score 8):

GCP has firewall rules for its VPC that work similar to AWS Security Groups. More details can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls). You can place your PostgreSQL database, Redis instance and Node.js server inside GCP VPC.

- Make Node.js server available to the public via DNS.
- Set `default-allow-internal` rule, so that only the services present in VPC can access each other (halting public access of DB and Redis)

As an alternative approach, you may also keep all three servers public and only allow Node.js IP address to access DB and Redis servers, but the above solution is recommended.

Comment: After setting the `default-allow-internal` rule, I would be accessing the PostgreSQL and Redis from the Node.js server via their respective public IP, right?

Comment: @IshaanOhri, technically they must only be allotted a private IP address and you'll use that. Another better option is to use their DNS. But in case your configurations make public IP address available you may use it as well. It will only be accessible in side the VPC.

Comment: A nice thing about security groups is that they are attached to interfaces and they can be used as the source / destination in rules on other security groups - you can have a group for web servers and DB servers with their rules referencing the other group as source and destination, even if IPs gets added / removed...

Comment: Another comment seems to indicate that "target tags" might be the solution to that part of the SG functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Security groups inside AWS are instance-attached firewall-like components. So for example, you can have a SG on an instance level, similar to configuring IP-tables on regular Linux.

On the other hand, Google Firewall rules are more on a Network level. I guess, for the level of "granularity", I'd say that Security Groups can be replaced to instance-level granularity, so then your alternatives are to use one of the following:

- firewalld
- nftables
- iptables

The thing is that in AWS you can also attach security groups to subnets. So SG's when attached to subnets, are also kind of similar to google firewalls, still, security groups provide a bit more granularity since you can have different security groups per subnet, while in GCP you need to have a firewall per Network. At this level, protection should come from firewalls in subnets.

Comment: this is not exactly correct. i agree with the concept firewall rule being in the network level. but a instance level granularity can be achived simply by using  target tags.
target tags can be used with many vms or even for each vm and then refere to those tags in your firewall rules. 

this allows us to achive the same level of control as security groups from AWS(with respect to VM instances)